# POST http://localhost:8000/sender 500 (Internal Server Error) laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I work in laravel vuejs project and i have this problem (POST http://localhost:8000/sender 500 (Internal Server Error))
my code vuejs:

```
methods: {
        send: function() {


        this.name = this.user.name;
        axios.post('/sender',{text: this.text, name: this.name });


          console.log(this.name);
          console.log(this.text);

          this.text = []; 
        }
    }
```

controller:

```
{

    event(new ChatEvent(['text' => $Ctext, 'name' => $Cname]));
}
```

ChatEvent : this is my code laravel event

{

```
public $datas;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($datas)
{
    //
    $this->datas = $datas;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('my-ch');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'ChatEvent';
}
```

}

Comment: What's the stack trace on your 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on your terminal

#### Chmod Storage

`sudo chmod 777 storage/ -R`

(NOTE: Use the 777 just to see if it solves the issue, this is not recommended in production, but if it solves the issue then you know what to fix, but 777 isn't an answer for production, it isn't safe)

#### Enable link to storage

`php artisan storage:link`